# Distributed Locks for Spring + Hibernate + Redis

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, hibernate, locking

I have been developing a multithreading web application using Spring mvc + Hibernate with redis for cache storage. I'm looking at finding a way to apply locks to controllers or services.

I can't make use of the locking mechanisms provided by Hibernate as it's meant to be applied at database level.

Here's an example:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(RestConstants.BASE_PATH + "/campaigns")
Class CampaignController  {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ApiResponse<?> findOne(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        Campaign campaign = repo.findOne(id);
        return toResponse(campaign);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public create(@RequestBody Campaign campaign) {
        //create an campaign here
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PATCH)
    public update(@RequestBody Campaign campaign) {
        //update an campaign here
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping(RestConstants.BASE_PATH + "/bulkCampaigns")
Class CampaignBulkController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public create(@RequestPart MultipartFile data) {
        /* 
        Data contains a list of campaigns with their details, 
         controller will iterate through the list and create all the campaigns.

         */
    }
}
```

While requests mapped to create method in CampaignBulkController is being processed, all the other writes on campaigns cannot be handled but reads are allowed.That is, requests to update or create campaign/campaigns should be dropped.

There are multiple servers and each server is multi-threaded.

I'm new to Spring and Hibernate, any idea or suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Based on your description, sounds like the database level is exactly what you want your locks on? Lock a table and other services will have to wait for the table to become unlocked before they can use it.

Comment: There's two things that make it slightly different: 1) while a special request is in process, other requests should be dropped and user gets a message like "cannot process your request while <name of the special request> is in process, please try again later. 2) I need to ensure when a request come in, it will be dropped only if a special request is being handled.

Comment: Do the special requests share tables with non-special requests? Are the special requests specific operations, or regular operations but with some special flag to indicate that they need to be treated differently? You should edit your question and provide some examples on what kind of use cases you can have.

Comment: @Kayaman I just updated my questions, let me know if you need some more details. Thx !

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to outline an initial answer here, possibly for later modification.

If you use a shared [ReadWriteLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html) and use read locks for the regular operations, you can have your privileged operations use write locks to block the regular operations.

```
// Regular operation tries to lock, if not successful a privileged operation is happening
if(!lock.readLock().tryLock())
    return cannotProcessResponse;

performRegularOperation();
lock.readLock().unlock();
```

---

```
// Privileged operation always waits for lock
lock.writeLock().lock();
performPrivilegedOperation();
lock.writeLock().unlock();
```

Now there are some issues with this approach. If using a single shared lock, only one privileged operation can run at a time. If this is an issue, multiple locks can be used and their read locks locked together (this can be deadlock prone, so care must be taken). Lock fairness should also be considered.

Comment: I just updated my question so that multiple privileged operations can't run at a time neither. And how would you recommend to implement the lock?

Comment: That makes it simpler. Just use a shared lock (e.g. inject it as a bean) and do as I outlined in my answer. And of course do a lot of reading before you just copy my code blindly.

Comment: Is bean thread-safe? Can I declare only one bean across multiple threads and multiple instances of web server?

Comment: You didn't mention that you have multiple servers. Then you'll have to get an external locking provider of some sort. You also need to learn a lot more about Spring, since "is bean thread-safe" doesn't make much sense.

Comment: looks like I need to do more research from now on, but thx! :)

Comment: Yeah, your question kinda ballooned from a simple "read/write locking" to "distributed locking", and it's a big leap. Although if you already have a shared redis, you can use that as the external locking provider and it'll be the same basic idea. You just need to write more code.

Comment: great to get the direction to start with, I'll check out the article to find something for myself, many thx :-)